# Настройка шаблонизатора PUG

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, pug

Такой вопрос, можно ли как-то настроить PUG что бы он на выходе форматировал код не в одну большую строку?

```
<div class="gallery__list our-work__gallery-big">
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-1.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-1.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Косметический ремонт стен и квартир"/><span>Косметический ремонт стен и квартир</span></a></div>
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-2.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-2.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Монтаж тёплого пола"/><span>Монтаж тёплого пола</span></a></div>
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-3.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-3.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Строительство домов и коттеджа"/><span>Строительство домов и коттеджа</span></a></div>
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-1.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-1.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Косметический ремонт стен и квартир"/><span>Косметический ремонт стен и квартир</span></a></div>
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-2.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-2.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Монтаж тёплого пола"/><span>Монтаж тёплого пола</span></a></div>
  <div class="gallery__image"><a href="img/repair/our-work-big-3.png" data-fancybox="gallery-work"><img src="img/repair/our-work-big-3.png" width="480" height="391" alt="Строительство домов и коттеджа"/><span>Строительство домов и коттеджа</span></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем файле gulpfile.js добавьте параметр **pretty: true** в таск компиляции pug:

```js
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.pug)
        .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```

Comment: Прописана такая настройка но всё ровно продолжает собирать блоки в длинный код. Скорей всего он не умеет нормально собирать html((

Comment: Можете приложить к посту свой gulpfile.js?